# Add animation to a Powerpoint slide after a video gets over?

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, animation

Basically I have a video which I'm playing inside a slide, and I need this video to fade away once it finishes playing to reveal the text box behind it.

I cant think of anything, or find any option for this in PowerPoint 2013 except for the delay button which I don't think will work out well for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little-known trick.  You can insert bookmarks into the video, then use them as triggers to fire animation events.

How:

After inserting the video, while it's selected, move the "scrub" bar to the position where you want the animation to occur.

Then on the ribbon, Playback tab, click Add Bookmark.  A little yellow dot appears below the video.  That's your bookmark.

Now with the video still selected, on the Animations tab, choose the exit animation type you want for the video then in Advanced Animation group, click trigger.  Choose On Bookmark, Bookmark 1.

Now when the video gets to the bookmark during playback, it'll trigger the disappear animation on the video itself.

Sorta like lifting itself by its own bootstraps, only backwards.